# FFMpeg command not working from java processbuilder on Mac

Tags: mac, java, ffmpeg

I am trying to merge two files through ffmpeg in mac(snow leopard 10.6.7). If I fire merge command through terminal it works fine, but if I fire same command through java process builder it give an error saying "moov atom not found videoFile.mp4 operation not permitted".
Could someone tell me what could be the issue.

**mereg command :** "ffmpeg -i audioFile.au -i videoFile.mp4 -sameq -ar 4100 -y mergedFile.mp4"
**ffmpeg version :** FFmpeg version svn-r26402-xuggle-4.0.900.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you use the terminal as root whereby java calls ffmpeg as non-root and so there are some permission issues...

Comment: @strauberry: I don't think it is a permission issue.

Comment: Altough it says "operation not permitted"?

Comment: Judging from your other question, have you gotten it to work? If so, consider answering the question yourself!